# Using *ngFor element within css to set image background

Tags: html, css, angular, contentful

I'm new to web dev and am trying to use an image that I get from Contenful content as a cover image within a div without using an `<img>`. It works well if I set it as a `[src]` of an `<img>` tag within my html file but as far as I could see, using it as an img tag:
`<img [src]="blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url" alt="">`
dint give me the sizing and styling I got from using a div with css file styling:

```
background: url('/assets/img/landscape3.jpg') center 50% fixed no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 50vh;
    padding-top: 15rem;
```

above I used the same image that exist on contentful but it looks more proportioned and sized as I want when i load it from my pc with a src url.

But since the image I want is from an *ngFor block: `*ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts.items"`
i have no idea how to set it as a background image of a `div` without using `<img>` tag
here is the code I used:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" gutterSize="1rem" rowHeight="4:3.5" class="main"
  *ngIf="blogPosts$ | async as blogPosts">
   <div *ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts.items">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="blogPost.fields.category === 'Science & 
      Tech'">
   <div class="tile">
     <div class="title"><p>{{ blogPost.fields.title }}</p></div>
     <img [src]="blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url" alt="">
    
   </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

This is want I want to try:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" gutterSize="1rem" rowHeight="4:3.5" class="main"
*ngIf="blogPosts$ | async as blogPosts">
<div class="for" *ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts.items">
<mat-grid-tile *ngIf="blogPost.fields.category === 'Science & Tech'">
<div class="tile">
<div class="title"><p>{{ blogPost.fields.title }}</p></div>
<div class="img"></div>
    
    
</div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

css:

```
.img {
margin-top: 0px;
background: url('blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url') center 
50% fixed no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover center 50% fixed no-repeat;}
```

So is it possible to use the resource im getting im my html *ngFor in my css file? or am I asking the right question when there is an alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url` property to inline style background of div with `img` class.
The following HTML code would work for you:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" gutterSize="1rem" rowHeight="4:3.5" class="main" *ngIf="blogPosts$ | async as blogPosts">
  <div class="for" *ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts.items">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="blogPost.fields.category === 'Science & Tech'">
      <div class="tile">
        <div class="title">
          <p>{{ blogPost.fields.title }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img" [style.background]="'url(' + blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url + ') center 50% fixed no-repeat'"></div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </div>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: simple solution, I would loved if it works but its not displaying the image

Comment: Would you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline styles for this. Those are style properties given to an element through a HTML tag attribute.

You should provide a default or fallback image in your styles and override it with inline styles like this:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>Default background color</div>
<div style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/roCfw.jpg');">Dynamic background image</div>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive in combination with inline CSS, angular-style

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="4" gutterSize="1rem" rowHeight="4:3.5" class="main"
  *ngIf="blogPosts$ | async as blogPosts">
   <div *ngFor="let blogPost of blogPosts.items">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="blogPost.fields.category === 'Science & 
      Tech'">
   <div class="tile">
     <div class="title" [bgImage]="blogPost.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url">
       <p>{{ blogPost.fields.title }}</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[bgImage]'
})
export class BgImageDirective {

  @Input() bgImage?: string;

  @HostBinding('style.background-image')
  private get finalImageUrl() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
      'url(' + (this.bgImage ?? '') + ') center 50% fixed no-repeat'
    );
  }

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: here I receive Can't bind to 'bgImage' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: @Barricvde that's because you have to declare a directive like I did.